# Different elements with the same name in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

In PHP, I would like to know how to provide the same name to different elements and still echo them out individually. I think the array mechanism works here but I don’t know how.

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='seat[]' id='something'/>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='seat[]' id='something1'/>"
```

Then to echo their values out I use the following:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['seat[]']))
    {
    echo ' ', $_POST['seat[]'] ; 
    }
?>
```

Please guide me!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just an array of data. You can access elements of it just like any other array:

```
foreach ($_POST['seat'] as $seat) {
    echo $seat . "<br>\n";
}
```

or using a numerical index:

```
echo $_POST['seat'][0]; // value of the first submitted checkbox
```

Comment: thanks john ur second advice was helpful i got my fix from it now its working.